# Saving output in txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python program that gives 3000 outputs in five seconds, and it gives millions of outputs in minutes. So I wanna know how to save the outputs in a '.txt' file automatically.

I think I need a python program to save all my outputs in a .txt file.
I use python 2 for some reason.

The problem I have is,

- windows does not have unlimited scrollback.
- I don't have ubuntu.
- If I try to copy my outputs my system hangs cuz it has just 4gb ram.

Help me guys, Thanks in advance.

Comment: You wrote the original program? add a file writer. https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_write.asp

if you didn't write it, then you need to post more information on how it outputs data, and what you have tried already.

Comment: "I think I need a python program to save all my outputs in a .txt file." Sure, go for it. [ask]

Comment: Did you try to redirect the output to a text file in command line, e.g. `python myApp.py > output.txt` ?

Answer (score 1):

Add this piece of code **before** you start outputting:

```
f = open(“file.txt”, “w+”)
```

Add this piece of code **during** outputting:

```
f.write(outputvar)
```

Add this piece of code **after** outputting:

```
f.close()
```

I hope this helps, if it doesn’t, please tell me.

Comment: I'll try dude, TYSM

Comment: No problem! Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

By output I am assuming you are talking about `print()` statements. You can redirect your standard output to have `print()` go to a file instead:

```
import sys

with open('output.txt','w') as f:
    sys.stdout = f
    print('Hello')
```

Comment: I'll try dude, TYSM